# My Windows 7 Product Key does not match with my current windows version

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installation, product-key

let me explain

Since I'd heard that Windows 10 was coming for free, I been  crazy waiting for the notification to appear on my task bar, but nothing would happen. Two months ago I was surprised with a "*your windows is not genuine* " notification. I was bummed, I couldn't believe it. Today I got the Windows 10 notification, but when doing the installing I forgot that I didn't have a product key since the pc did not brought one, but I finally found it in a sticker attached to the computer. Surprisingly my key was rejected. Now the sticker says is a product key for Windows 7 Home Premium, the windows version I have installed is Windows 7 Professional.

How do I solve this? I have no CD installation for windows 7 home premium.

What are my options and what can I do?

Comment: Sorry for my grammar, english is not my native language.

Comment: How you solve it is you a Windows 10 Home Version 1611 and install Windows 10.  When asked for a product key you supply the Windows 7 Home license key you have.  This will only work on a Version 1511 .ISO any version of the .ISO released before Nov-12-2015 will not work.  You can also purchase Windows 10 Professional if you want to keep your personal files and applications installed.

Comment: Please post the make and model of pc.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your machine came with Windows 7 Home Premium preinstalled, and it was later upgraded with a copy of Windows 7 Professional which was either pirated or using a duplicate product key.  You should however still be able to get Windows 10 from the OS that was previously installed on your machine.  You should see [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-windows-product-key#get-windows-product-key=windows-7) for info, and contact Microsoft support.

Comment: Why the downvote?